# What's the deal with boss events?

Tags: the-secret-world

I'm specifically interested in the current [Gilded Rage event](http://unfair.co/gaming/the-secret-world/the-secret-world-the-gilded-rage-event-information/#comment-2548), but this really applies to pretty much all of the events.

1. Should I even bother trying to participate in these large events if I don't have QL10 gear? The event bosses seem to spawn all over, but apparently have the same stats regardless of which zone they spawn in. If one is in a low-level zone where I can get to the fight and won't get insta-ganked by random wanderers, will I still die instantly against a boss? Will I be able to contribute meaningfully?
2. I joined the relevant chat channel to find out more about where the bosses were up, but I'm not sure how to interpret the messages. They typically say "Dim (number), Serv (number), (acronym), (coordinates)". I know the acronym is the zone and the coordinates are where in the zone. Dim is dimension and serv is server, I assume, but do I have to wait for a boss to spawn in my dimension/server (how do I even know which one I'm in?), or is there a way for me to switch over?
3. How does one participate? Just show up and zerg the boss? Or do people normally form properly coordinated groups? If more than one group (raid group?) is involved, does only one group get the drop(s)?
4. How do drops work? Does everyone (in the killing group?) get a drop, or are they rolled on as usual? If rolled on, how many items typically drop? What are your chances of getting one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The boss events are designed to be done by upwards of 50-odd players at once. At a low-level, i'd recommend using long-range weapons and just watching out for the aura attacks like Anima Leech / Upheaval - leave close range fighting to the tanks. Don't worry too much about contributing in a meaningful fashion, as the boss HP doesn't scale with the number of players like in MMOs like Guild Wars 2.

2) The chat channel will usually only announce the Dim / Serv when a boss is present. Befriend the spotter saying the message and meetup on them, if the server isn't full you'll get to the Anima Well nearest the fight. FAQs are regularly posted in the chat channel explaining this.

3) At your low-level, you're best as a small-time DPS. Sit there, fire your weapon, and wait 10mins. Zerging the boss is honestly the best tactics, although you might need to wait until high-level tanks come along to keep the boss occupied. All drops are gotten via a blue mini-mission that activates and completes when the boss dies.

4) The drops are gotten via a mission activated when the boss dies, when is given to anyone who tagged the boss and is still in the zone. It drops some PAX and a Shem bag, which contains costumes, signet bags, and the all important pet parts.